# Spring Boot | Making another Entity class object in Entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to create a library API. I have a Book Entity and a Member Entity.
In Book class, I have created an of Member class to check whether Book is given to Member or not.
Likewise for Member class.

But the thing is I am getting an error for doing such

```
Could not determine type for: com.example.demo.Member, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(member)]
Could not determine type for: com.example.demo.Member, at table: book, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(member)]
```

I have found many answers related to this topic but ...
They all were using classes in collection
**List**
What annotation should I add to them??

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private int page;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private Date dateOfBookRegistration;
    private Member member;
    
    // getters setters ...
}
```

**Member**

```
@Entity
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateOfRegistration;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Date dateOfGettingBook;
    private Book book;

    // getters setters ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a association between the two enities.
Depending your needs you could for instance use a uni-directional One-To-One association:

by changing the code of the Book entity like follows...

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Member member
```

The id of the member entity will be stored as a foreign key in the book record.

Comment: if you want more infos you could check https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one